# PHP-FFMpeg filters()->resize() throw Use of undefined constant RESIZEMODE_INSET

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm using `PHP-FFMpeg` to use FFMpeg with php, unfortunately I can't set resize filter.

This is my code:

```
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mov');

$dimension = new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1920, 1080);
$video->filters()
      ->resize($dimension, RESIZEMODE_INSET, true, 1)
      ->synchronize();

$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264');
$format->setAudioChannels(2)->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);
$video->save($format, 'video.mp4');
```

But it throws this error:

`Use of undefined constant RESIZEMODE_INSET - assumed 'RESIZEMODE_INSET'`

I tried also:

`->resize($dimension, 'RESIZEMODE_INSET', true, 1)`

and

`->resize($dimension, 'inset', true, 1)`

But I can't get the video converted without stretching.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is `RESIZEMODE_INSET`?

Comment: @zerkms as described in the official API documentation of `PHP-FFMpeg` should be one of the four possible constants passed to the method `__construct(Dimension $dimension, $mode = self::RESIZEMODE_FIT, $forceStandards = true, $priority)` the default is `RESIZEMODE_FIT` here you can find the php of the filter https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/blob/master/src/FFMpeg/Filters/Video/ResizeFilter.php

Comment: So, it's a class constant, not just a constant. Prepend it with a `classname::` where `classname` is the name of the class where it's defined. `ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_INSET`

Comment: @zerkms yes, sorry.

Comment: @zerkms ok now isn't throwing any error but the video has anamorphosis so it's stretched

Comment: I would suggest to check what command is generated and compare with what command you expect it to generate. Then, depending on results - file a bug or fix your code.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for helping me, I found that I was using the wrong filter: resize instead of pad

Answer (score 0):

**efine('RESIZEMODE_INSET','inset');**
You need to define RESIZEMODE_INSET .
It can be const or define or variable.
$RESIZEMODE_INSET = "inset";

```
<?php
define('RESIZEMODE_INSET','inset');
        $video = $ffmpeg->open($video_file);
        $dimension = new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(1280, 720);
        $video->filters()
            ->resize($dimension, RESIZEMODE_INSET, true, 1)
            ->synchronize();

        $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('aac', 'libx264');
        $format->setAudioChannels(2)->setAudioKiloBitrate(256);
        $video->save($format, 'video.mp4');
```